# Adding overfull hbox 'slugs' to final document version

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, draft

I'm using a `documentclass` which looks dramatically different in `draft` mode compared to `final`. I'm preparing my document for the `final` formatting, so I don't want to pass the `draft` option.

However I *would* like to see overfull hboxes marked with the visible black bar (slug) in the same way as `\documentclass[draft]{article}`. Is there a way to turn on this visualization separately to using the `draft` option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set `\overfullrule=1mm` to display overfull lines regardless of the draft mode.

Comment: (In `article.cls`, the option is defined by `\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}`, hence `5pt` is the default length.)